# Advisable to remove the Session/Keepalive log data coming from Applications to Azure App Insights

Tags: session, azure-application-insights, keep-alive

We have a web-application hosted on Azure and it sends Telemetry to App Insights and the Dev team is asking if it is ok to Turn off sending the SESSION/KEEPALIVE data thats being posted from web-application. Will this affect any functionality like User Flows etc in Application Insights? 
Any guidance on this?
Following is sample data:-

timestamp | id | source | name | url | success | resultCode | duration | performanceBucket
-- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | --
2019-09-25T16:00:31.8191577Z | \|Ac34D.9fIx+.4c3e0b35_ | POST session/keepalive | http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/session/keepalive | TRUE | 200 | 15.8274 | <250ms
2019-09-25T16:00:42.7423811Z | \|Ac34D.FqSNy.83ee6e0d_ | POST session/keepalive | http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/session/keepalive | TRUE | 200 | 38.3679 | <250ms
2019-09-25T16:00:48.716939Z | \|Ac34D.h8kwN.34c0b012_ | POST session/keepalive | http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/session/keepalive | TRUE | 200 | 16.0359 | <250ms
2019-09-25T16:00:54.1607213Z | \|Ac34D.v2qfF.4c3e0b36_ | POST session/keepalive | http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/session/keepalive | TRUE | 200 | 15.2518 | <250ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in Applications Insights typically target a specific set of telemetry item types.

For instance, user flows UI leverages `PageView` and `CustomEvent` telemetry types. Therefore, if keep alive is reported as one of those types it will be displayed in that UI.

However, if the example above is `Dependency` telemetry, then that view won't be affected.

In general, if you'd like to drop some of the telemetry before it reaches AI and is processed for storage, you'd use `TelemetryProcessor` (in case of Java Script SDK, [`TelemetryInitializer`](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-js#telemetry-initializers)) to filter it out:

```
var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
  if (envelope.data.someField == 'keepalive') return false;
};
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```